# separate_rows with unequal size of strings in R

Tags: r, tidyr

Suppose I have a dataset like this:

```
   a       b
"1/2/3" "a/b/c"
 "3/5"  "e/d/s"
  "1"     "f"
```

I want to use `separate_rows` But I can't because of the second row. How can I find these kind of rows?

Comment: What's the output you're trying to get? How did you try doing this, and what was wrong with the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the rows with unequal numbers of '/' symbols by doing:

```r
which(lengths(strsplit(df$a, '/')) != lengths(strsplit(df$b, '/')))
#> [1] 2
```

Presumably these rows contain data input mistakes, since the number of rows implied by each entry is different.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can directly count the number of "/" in each column, and output the row that does not have equal number of "/".

```
library(stringr)

with(df, which(str_count(a, "/") != str_count(b, "/")))
[1] 2
```

#### Input data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("1/2/3", "3/5", "1"), b = c("a/b/c", "e/d/s", 
"f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Nice to have a tidverse equivalent, +1!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `cSplit` would help

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
cSplit(df, c("a", "b"), sep = "/", "long") %>% 
   filter(if_any(c(a, b), complete.cases))
```

-output

```
      a      b
   <int> <char>
1:     1      a
2:     2      b
3:     3      c
4:     3      e
5:     5      d
6:    NA      s
7:     1      f
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("1/2/3", "3/5", "1"), b = c("a/b/c", "e/d/s", 
"f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```